# Function rLGCP fails when trying to generate an LGCP with covariate data using spatstat

Tags: r, spatial, spatstat

I'm trying to simulate a log gaussian cox process based on an image array for the covariate field, and a matern covariance function for the GMRF field, based pretty much exactly on the example given in "Advanced Spatial Modeling with Stochastic Partial Differential Equations Using R and INLA" ([https://becarioprecario.bitbucket.io/spde-gitbook/ch-lcox.html](https://stackoverflow.com)). However the code as its written in the online textbook is throwing a warning when it generates the LGCP.

The code used is here:

```
library(spatstat)

win <- owin(c(0, 3), c(0, 3))
npix <- 300
spatstat.options(npixel = npix)

beta0 <- 3
sigma2x <- 0.2
range <- 1.2
nu <- 1

set.seed(7)

x0 <- seq(0, 3, length=npix)
y0 <- seq(0, 3, length=npix)
gridcov <- outer(x0, y0, function(x,y) cos(x) - sin(y - 2))

beta1 <- 0
sum(exp(beta0 + beta1 * gridcov) * diff(x0[1:2]) * diff(y0[1:2]))

lg.s.c <- rLGCP('matern', im(beta0 + beta1 * gridcov, xcol = x0,
  yrow = y0), var = sigma2x, scale = range / sqrt(8), 
  nu = 1, win = win)
xy.c <- cbind(lg.s.c$x, lg.s.c$y)[, 2:1]
n.c <- nrow(xy.c)

Lam <- attr(lg.s.c, 'Lambda')
rf.s.c <- log(Lam$v)
```

The returned warning is `the images ‘e1’ and ‘e2’ were not compatible`  and the resulting intensity field rf.s.c has dimensions 562 x 562 whereas the the input x and y arrays are 1x100 (the intensity field should be 100 x 100), and is entirely NA values.

Could someone help me understand this warning and why the example is failing?

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem here is that the input arguments `win` and `mu` are **incompatible** in this example.

The `spatstat` code has not automatically repaired the incompatibility, and I guess we could call that a bug.

In your example, `win` is the square *[0,3] x [0,3]*, while `mu` was constructed by something like

```
x0 <- seq(0, 3, length=npix)
y0 <- seq(0, 3, length=npix)
MU <- im(......., xcol=x0, yrow=y0)
```

The example seems to expect that `MU` will be an image inside *[0,3] x [0,3]* but this is not true:

```
> MU
real-valued pixel image
300 x 300 pixel array (ny, nx)
enclosing rectangle: [-0.0050167, 3.005] x [-0.0050167, 3.005] units
```

In an image object in `spatstat`, the coordinates `xcol` and `yrow` are the coordinates of the **centres** of the pixels. For an image that is defined inside *[0,3] x [0,3]*, the coordinates `xcol` will lie strictly inside the interval *(0,3)*.

```
> as.im(win)$xcol[1:4]
[1] 0.005 0.015 0.025 0.035
```

I have now fixed the code in `rLGCP` (in `spatstat.random` version `3.2-2.002` available from [the GitHub repository](https://github.com/spatstat/spatstat.random)) so that it now automatically fixes the incompatibility.

Also, some advice: to make a pixel image where you want the pixel values to be defined by a function `f(x,y)` of the spatial coordinates, it would be safer and neater to use `as.im.function`:

```
meanfun <- function(x,y, beta0, beta1) {
       beta0 + beta1 * (cos(x) - sin(y - 2))
}
MU <- as.im(meanfun, dimyx=300, W=win, beta0=3, beta1=0)
```

You can specify the raster dimensions using arguments like `dimyx`, `eps` or specify the raster by using an existing pixel image as the argument `W`.

Answer (score 0):

This may very well be a bug in `spatstat`. Recently, new code was added for simulation of LGCPs due to the package RandomFields no longer being on CRAN. We will investigate further and you can track the status of the issue on GitHub:
https://github.com/spatstat/spatstat.random/issues/2